# how to remove question mark form url in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, routes, frameworks

how to remove question mark form url in laravel
i use laravel 5.4 and i get this trey to use query in the link but it don't work
http://localhost/shooping-cart/public/add-to-cart/id?1

i want to remove id and question mark form url 
i use laravel 5.4

```
Route::get('/add-to-cart/{id}', [
    'uses' => 'ProductController@getAddToCart',
    'as' => 'product.addToCart'
]);
```

Comment: There shouldn't be a question mark in case your ID is just `1`.

Comment: should "shooping" actually be "shopping"?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the problem is in the way you generate the link. For this route you should use `route()` helper like this:

```
{{ route('product.addToCart', $productId) }}
```

Or create a link manually:

```
{{ url('add-to-cart/'.$productId) }}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use **?** mark after id like `{id?}`
And in the view file, generate link like this..

```
<a href="{{ route('product.addToCart') }}/your_id">Link Name</a>
```

It will definitely work.

```
Route::get('/add-to-cart/{id?}', [
    'uses' => 'ProductController@getAddToCart',
    'as' => 'product.addToCart'
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

{{ route('product.addToCart', $productId) }}

Answer (score 0):

I think this is just the way Laravel constructs the URL. Its more of an aesthetic than functional choice. If you do not wish to see a question mark in your url when performing GET request then use a named route with parameters.

```
<a href="{{ route('questions.show',['question' => $task->id]) }}">View</a>
```

If you access your controller by matching URL thru the router class.

```
<form method="get" action="/questions/{{$task->id}}">
 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-sm">View</button>
</form>
```

You will see a question mark "?" appended to the end of your URL.